# Yacc how to pass multiple values up tree

Tags: c, yacc

I am writing a compiler in `C` using `lex` and `yacc` and having trouble understanding passing values up the syntax tree in `yacc`.

Suppose I have a line of grammar like

```
arg_list : exp
| arg_list ',' exp;
```

which is supposed to model something like the parameter part inside a function eg

```
x = f(3+4, 2*5);
```

How would I use the `$$=...` to pass values up the tree for the second instruction? I know I can set something like `$$=$1+$3` to pass up sum of two values and `$$=$1` for the first instruction. But how would I pass up multiple values if they are not related. I am not doing any operations with the `3+4` and `2*5`, they are separate computations but I want to pass them both up. Or am I misunderstanding something of how yacc works?

I have found some stuff online using `unions` but had trouble compiling them.

Am I supposed to use

```
%union {
struct pair {
    char *s_value;
    int i_value;
    char op_value;
} pair;
int single_int;
}
```

in any way? I don't really understand what the `union` does. It would be great if someone could provide a very simple `yacc` and `lex` file which compiles and illustrates an example of passing multiple unrelated values up. I can't seem to find one online.

Comment: [bison manual on semantic values](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantic-Values). But that only explains the bison `%union` directive. (It's important to understand but not directly relevant to your question.) You need to construct some kind of data structure which can hold multiple values -- linked lists are quite popular, as are stacks and even vectors. Also you need to clarify your requirements. Are you compiling or evaluating? You might need a collectiom of values, or a collection of parse nodes...

Comment: Do you mean a global linked list that can be reused? I pass pointer to head of linked list up and i know that above i should extract all elements in all nodes of linked list in order? Do you mean something like that?

Comment: "something like that". But lose the global.

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~stremler/2003_CS530/YaccAndLex.html for simplier explanations.

What you need to build is something like a tree with the %union.

```
%code requires{
struct Node {
    struct Node* others;    
    <<<something that can hold EXP symbol>>>;
  };
}
%union {

<<<anything you want more>>>;
struct Node *node;
}
```

grammer:

```
arg_list : exp { $$=$1 }
| arg_list ',' exp; {
                      struct Node nd;
                      nd.others=$1;
                      nd.<<exp>>= $3;
                      $$=nd;
                    }
```

This will build a tree of struct Node. 
https://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/yacc.html